# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1" in android

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have this Kotlin class

```
class CategoryJsonData(val category: List<Category>) 
data class Category(val _id:Double, val category_name:String, val sub_category_name:String, val price:Int)
```

At this line, I get an error

```
val jsonData = gson.fromJson(body, CategoryJsonData::class.java)
```

When I parse this JSON

```
{ "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1", "category_name": "electrical", "sub_category_name": "switches meters and fuses", "price": 300 }
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1"

`5b80393f7fca491488980fe1(_id)` is generated by mongoose using nodejs.
showing this error while trying to hit API.

```
09-18 23:26:47.026 18264-18542/com.hiretheskill.skill E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.hiretheskill.skill, PID: 18264
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1"
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextDouble(JsonReader.java:909)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$2.read(Gson.java:284)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$2.read(Gson.java:278)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
        at com.hiretheskill.skill.SubCategories$fetchJsonData$client$1.onResponse(SubCategories.kt:45)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Is `CategoryJsonData` a class you wrote?

Comment: this is the json data which i am trying to get in android

Comment: {
            "_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1",
            "category_name": "electrical",
            "sub_category_name": "switches meters and fuses",
            "price": 300
        }

Comment: Change the `_id` field in your Category class to a `String` and you should be good.

Comment: thanks alot it worked!

Answer (score 3):

In your JSON, this is a String `"_id": "5b80393f7fca491488980fe1"`

In your class, you defined it as a Double `val _id:Double`

You need to change that to be a String since you have non-numerical characters in the JSON value